# How to find/define the closest diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering how to solve the general problem of a closest diagonal matrix in a closed form, if this is possible.

That is, assume you have any known square n-by-n matrix $A$ and an unknown n-length vector $w$.

Solve for $A \approx diag(w)$

In other words, find $w$ that minimizes $\|(A - diag(w))^{T}(A-diag(w))\|_{2}$

Comment: Note that the matrices form an inner product space, and that the set of diagonal matrices are a subspace.  It suffices to compute the projection of $A$ onto this subspace (which amounts to setting the non-diagonal entries equal to $0$).

Comment: $\|(A-diag(w))\|_{2}$ is an as good candidate as the one you propose.